# Show that homomorphism with idempotent is a projection

Tags: vector-spaces

**Setup:** $\varphi :V \rightarrow V$ is a homomorphism with $\varphi\circ \varphi =\varphi, U_1=\{\varphi(v) |v\in V\}, U_2=\{v-\varphi(v) |v\in V\}$

**Task:**  Now I have to show, that $\forall u_1\in U_1, u_2\in U_2 : \varphi(u_1)=u_1, \varphi(u_2)=0$.

**Here is my proof sketch**

$u_1\in U_1$  means that there is a $w_1\in V : u_1=\varphi(w_1)$. Now we can conclude

$\varphi(u_1)=\varphi(\varphi(w_1))=\varphi(w_1)=u_1$. Therefore $\varphi(u_1)=u_1$

---

$u_2\in U_2$ menas that there is a $w_2\in V : u_2=w_2-\varphi(w_2)$. Therefore

$\varphi(u_2)=\varphi(w_2-\varphi(w_2))=\varphi(w_2)-w_2$ ...

Here is my problem, I'm not sure how I can go on with the proof. And is part one of correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you perchance mean to write $\varphi \circ \varphi = \varphi$ rather than $p \circ p = p$ in your second line?  If not, what is $p$?  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, your right. Thanks1!

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi(u_2) = \varphi (w_2- \varphi(w_2)) = \varphi(w_2) - \varphi(\varphi(w_2)) = \varphi(w_2) - \varphi(w_2) = 0$, where linearity and idempotentcy were used in this order.

Comment: your right, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome.